# JS script at end of body doesn't consistently run/complete

Tags: javascript, html

I tag links to my website with a get parameter, tid. In my footer, I have a script (just regular JS, not jquery or anything) that appends tid to certain links in the DOM, when applicable.

These links are hard-coded with a default value in the href. So, in the event someone doesn't have JS enabled, I will record link clicks tagged to the default value.

I receive a lot of link clicks where the script works correctly. But the problem is, I also get a lot of link clicks with the default tag.

My ideas for where things are going wrong, from most to least likely:

- script takes too long to run/finish. This could happen since other things like Tag Manager are loading first. **How can I make it run faster, and also ensure that the DOM has fully loaded?**
- user has JS turned off (unlikely)
- script is failing. This is out of my area of expertise, and I can't even confirm that it's happening.

The script is located immediately before the  tag, so the DOM will have loaded. The website is here:
https://www.scaredycut.com
I commented "tag script" right above the script in question.

I know it's hard to diagnose something like this where the script might fail a part of the time. Any tools that could help me see how this script is working, or suggestions on finding help for solving this?

Comment: `<script src='jquery...></script>` then all other `<script src="..."></script>` then `<script>` JS/jQuery code here `</script>` then `</body>` then `</html>` nothing different like `<iframe>` should be in between theses tags you must place anything else before these tags. Also `id` isn't really needed for `<script>`

Comment: You could try looking into the defer attribute of the script tag (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)).